# Dictionary overwriting

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm having an issue where my dictionary's key values are being overwritten rather than added.
`my_list` is a list of a tuples, where each tuple is consisting of 3 values: `(string, string, int)`.

```
for i in range(0, len(my_list)):

    dict = {my_list[i][1]: my_list[i][2]}
    graph[my_list[i][0]] = dict

    dict = {my_list[i][0]: my_list[i][2]}
    graph[my_list[i][1]] = dict

    print(graph)
```

If `my_list = [("A", "B", 1), ("A", "C", 3)]` then this codes outputs `{B:{A:1},A:{C:3},C:{A:3}}`. However, what I want it to output is `{B:{A:1},A:{B:1, C:3},C:{A:3}}`.

Comment: As a side note: Don't call your dictionary `dict`; that hides the name `dict` for the actual type, which means you'll never be able to call it to do things like `dict(my-list-of-tuples)` anymore.

Comment: What's the logic/basic idea behind the output you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're writing `graph[my_list[i][0]] = dict`, so of course that just assigns `dict` to the key `my_list[i][0]` in `graph`.

What you want to do is update the existing dictionary with `dict`, like this:

```
graph[my_list[i][0]].update(dict)
```

But what if this is the first one? Then there is no dict yet to update.

You can use `setdefault` to fetch the value if present, or set a default value and fetch that if not, and then you have something to update:

```
graph.setdefault(my_list[i][0], {}).update(dict)
```

Or you can use a `collections.defaultdict`, which essentially automatically turns any missing lookup into a `setdefault` call:

```
graph = defaultdict(dict)

# later, in your loop
graph[mylist[i][0]].update(dict)
```

By the way, the above shows why you shouldn't name your dict `dict`. You need to be able to access the actual builtin `dict` type to give it to `defaultdict`. If you've hidden that name with some other value, this will give you an error. So name your dict something like `dct`—or, better, something actually meaningful.

In Python, there should be one obvious way to do it. Which one is the obvious way here? Well, it depends on what you're doing with `graph` *after* this code. If you want every failed lookup to return an empty dict, use `defaultdict`; if you want every failed lookup to raise a `KeyError`, use a normal `dict` with `setdefault`.